# Issue commiting to Genexus Server

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd, genexus-gam

I'm following this tutorial: https://training-legacy.genexus.com/en/training/global/courses/smart-devices-en/introduction-to-genexus-16

and i have the Genexus 16-trial version.

In the end of the "First Transaction design" lesson, you have to send the changes to Genexus server, 
[but this is what happens when i open the "Team Development" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geTO0.png)

If i enter the link in the message, from my browser https://sandbox.genexusserver.com/v16/ i can login normally, authenticating with Genexus Account and i can see my knowledge base in there.

I have pending commits, following the steps of the tutorial but i can't commit them. I wrote a commit message and pressed commit at the right bottom corner of the window and it rerturns a similar message:

error: GAM11: The user or password is incorrect.

Failed: Commit

The only 3 user and password i found were:

When creating the KB (if you disable Windows NT integrated security) but i couldn't find a valid user id and password for that, also the tutorial doesn't do this so i doubt this is it.

At tools -> Genexus Account, i can enter my email and password, and i think the IDE asks you to do this when sending the KB to the Server the first time, but when i fill it with the same credentials i use to login in to the website and press "sign in" now, it doesn't give any response.

Lastly There's the Windows Generic credential that is created but i don't even know how, just found it browsing at the genexus wiki and i have no idea what interaction it has with all this (if it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is below preferences. If you do not have the view near KB explorer then you should go to the menu toolbar —> View —> Other tool windows --> preferences in order to activate it.

[Team Development properties in Full Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPwol.png)

Note: Trial has no properties available below TeamDevelopment Tab

[Team Development properties in Trial Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw4jG.png)

Comment: I think trial version doesn't have this option at all:

[image](https://imgur.com/a/Mh5jvmz)

Comment: Please, select the Tab |"Team Development" and validate if the properties Server Username and Server Password are correct. I have updated my previous comment with the new image.

Comment: I have tried this before but there's no property shown when i open the Team Development tab: [image](https://imgur.com/a/8NQKFqJ)

Comment: Thanks Guigas, I could reproduce this error with the Trial and reported to development. I will let you know the progress shortly. A valid workaround in the meantime is to create a new KB and import the modified objects from the previous one.

Comment: Another Valid workaround is to delete this file: ServerListData located under C:\Users\<<YourUser>>\AppData\Roaming\GeneXus\GeneXus\16Trial

So, the next time you open the Team Development view your credentials will be requested.

Comment: Thank you, i deleted the ServerListData file and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Could you double check if you have the correct credentials below TeamDevelopment node?

[Team Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htbdB.png)

Comment: couldn't find this option here, looking for team on the search bar also shows nothing

Comment: [am i looking on the right place? left bar, KB Explorer](https://imgur.com/P2oZsbL)